# Query on PFUser according to key value (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I have PFUser saved as a pointer in this class. I'd like to retrieve the user's first name and corresponding "point value" 
My attempt below to append that data to it's cell value, but it is only returning the last retrieved object for that key value.

```
  var innerQuery : PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
  innerQuery.whereKeyExists("objectId")
  let query = PFQuery(className: "myClass")
  query.whereKey("userId", matchesQuery: innerQuery)
  query.whereKey("points", greaterThan: 1000)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                if let objects = query.findObjects() as? [PFObject]{
                    for object in objects {

            if let listPoints = object.objectForKey("points") as? Int {


                            var temp = String(listPoints)
                            cell.pointStatus.text = temp

                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            else{
                println(error?.description)
            }


        }
```

I retrieve the users first name and profile picture in a separate call. Everything is functional aside from the query for points.

```
    if let pfuser = userProfile["first_name"] as? String{
    if let pfimage = userProfile["profile_picture"] as? PFFile{ 

    pfimage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (result, error) in

        cell.userIcon.image = UIImage(data: result!)
         cell.userName.text = username

    })

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are only writing the value of `listPoints` to one cell in

```
var temp = String(listPoints)
cell.pointStatus.text = temp
```

If you want to have multiple point values to be displayed, the cell reference will need to be changed.